# Add Serializer on Reverse Relationship - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a `Cart` model and a `CartItem` model. The `CartItem` model has a `ForeignKey` to the `Cart` model.

Using Django Rest Framework I have a view where the API user can display the `Cart`, and obviously then I want to include the `CartItem` in the respone.

I set up my Serializer like this:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    cartitem_set = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'user', 
            'date_created', 
            'voucher', 
            'carrier', 
            'currency', 
            'cartitem_set', 
        )
```

My problem is the second line, `cartitem_set = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True)`.

I get AttributeErrors saying `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'`.  ('product' is a field in the `CartItem` model. If I exclude product from the `CartItemSerializer` I just get a new AttributeError with the next field and so on. No matter if I only leave 1 or all fields in the Serializer, I will get a error.

My guess is that for some reason Django REST Framework does not support adding Serializers to reverse relationships like this. Am I wrong? How should I do this?

PS

The reason why I want to use the `CartItemSerializer()` is because I want to have control of what is displayed in the response.

Comment: try `cartitem_set = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)`

Comment: what does your CartItem model Foreign Key key look like?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ahmed Hosny was correct in his answer. It required the `many` parameter to be set to `True` to work.

So final version of the `CartSerializer` looked like this:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cartitem_set = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True, many=True) # many=True is required
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        depth = 1
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'date_created', 
            'voucher', 
            'carrier', 
            'currency', 
            'cartitem_set', 
        )
```

Comment: can we change name cartitem_set to items ?

Comment: You can change the name by doing something like:  items = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True, many=True, source='cartitem_set')

Comment: You can change cartitem_set name, from related_name. In class CartItem : cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name='items') , then in "fields" inside serializer, you must use name items

Comment: I have an issue here. I am not getting any column as cartitem_set  in the JSON response any idea? (Data is present). Response returns without cartitem_set key pair .

Comment: Is it possible to use this solution then filter the items returned in the set?

Comment: @Helen you can pass in a source kwarg to the field and set a custom source if you want.

Comment: What would the syntax of that look like? I've currently got source set to source='cartitem_set' to change the name, but since it's a string, how would I pass a filter or a queryset into it? Appreciate your help Marcus.

Comment: This solution is incredibly slow for bigger queries, any way to increase the performance here?

Comment: Had to use a prefetch_related on the query of course: prefetch_related('cartitem_set')

Comment: man, I love you, I've spent 3 hours that comes to an end with that "many=True"

Answer (score 13):

It's important to define a related name in your models, and to use that related name in the serializer relationship:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class CartItem(models.Model):
   cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, related_name='cart_items')
   items = models.IntegerField()
```

Then in your serializer definition you use those exact names:

```
class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cart_items = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
       model = Cart
       fields = ('name', 'cart_items',)
```

Comment: This did not fix the problem. Still get `'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'product'` error when I try to use `cart_items = CartItemSerializer(read_only=True)`

Comment: In the original question he keeps the implicit related name: cartitem_set

Comment: Yes, this is very important for reverse relationship to work

Answer (score 0):

It would be wise to share your whole code, that is model and serializers classes. However, perhaps this can help debug your error,

> My serializer classes

```
class CartItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItem
        fields = ('id')

class CartSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    #take note of the spelling of the defined var
    _cartItems = CartItemSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Cart
        fields = ('id','_cartItems')
```

> Now for the Models

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    _cartItems = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    #Protect Forbids the deletion of the referenced object. To delete it you will have to delete all objects that reference it manually. SQL equivalent: RESTRICT.
class Meta:
    ordering = ('id',)

class Cart(models.Model):
    class Meta:
    ordering = ('id',)
```

> For a detailed overview of relationships in django-rest-framework, please refer their official [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/)